# Hard Drive Autorun Program

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, autorun

I am trying to run a program, once a user double clicks on a hard drive(not Windows HDD).

My idea was to:
create an autorun.inf file, and once the user clicks on the HDD, the program will excute.

My problem I'm having...
I can't get my autorun.inf file to work.

It contains the following:

[autorun]
open=hello.exe

When I right click the .inf file and click 'install', it gives me an error - "Installation Failed".

Any help, on the autorun.inf file or another way to run my program, will be much appreciated.

My computer O.S Specs are:

Windows XP Pro.
SP 3.

Answer (score 1):

On a general note, the 'Installation Failed' message can be displayed when autorun is invoked by a logged on user who is not a member of the local Administrator's group (on Vista, you may need to right-click autorun.inf and select 'Run as administrator').

Also, here are several links that have general information on autorun (and the 'NoDriveTypeAutoRun' registry entry

Create an Autorun CD-ROM for Applications That You Create by Using Microsoft Visual Studio .NET :-

Steps are

```
1) Start Visual Studio .NET.
2) Create a simple Console Application or Windows Application.
3) Build the application.
4) On the File menu, point to New, and then click Project.
5) In Project Types, click Setup and Deployment Projects. In Templates, click Setup    projects
6) Name the project Setup, and then click OK.
7) In Solution Explorer, right-click your Setup project, click Add, and then click File.
```

8) In the File name text box, type the absolute path of the executable that you built in step3, and then click Open.

9) On the Build menu, click Build Solution.
10) Start any text editor (such as Notepad).

```
Paste the following code in the text editor, and then save the file as Autorun.inf:

[autorun] 
open=Setup.exe
```

Note :-  To prepare an Autorun CD-ROM for the Visual Studio .NET application that you built in step 3, copy the files that were generated in step 9 and the Autorun.inf file that you created in step 11 to the CD-ROM.